# I could not download specific page via perl get, bash command GET and wget

Tags: perl, get, wget

I have an issue with downloading a page,

```
my $url='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore?linkname=pcassay_nucleotide&from_aid=504934,1806,1805,1674';
```

I can browse following with a browser but when I run bash command in perl or linux shell,

```
GET $url >OUTPUT1;  # Even it does not write anything to file "OUPUT1"
```

When I try wget, It downloads but not correct ,I mean with --> `<title>Error - Nucleotide - NCBI</title>`. I want the page with items , but it returns me a page without items.

```
my $html = qx{wget --quiet --output-document=OUTPUT1 $url};
```

**Note: I noticed a few minutes ago, url is ok with Mozilla firefox, but it can not be browsed via google chrome. it is weird, probably my issue related with this too. Any idea?

Code from link:

```
my $url='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore?linkname=pcassay_nucleotide&from_aid=504934,1806,1805,1674';


my $html = qx{wget --quiet --output-document=OUTPUT11 $url};

# wget get something, but it does not get items, it gets what I get via google chrome

`GET $url2 >OUTPUT11`; # it does not write anything to file,
```

Comment: What is the module you are using to do the http GET ?

Comment: Please post full code for `GET $url > OUTPUT1`

It looks like you are using the shell commands from LWP, since you are piping with `>`. If you run this in perl, you need to output your result in another way.

Comment: I don't use module, I am running bash command  via ` `.  I also used LWP::Simple; but it does not change anything too.

Comment: Don't "add code here". Include it in your question. Stack Overflow doesn't like offsite links.

Comment: If you are asking about downloading the whole page, with links try `wget -E -k -p http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore?linkname=pcassay_nucleotide`

Comment: If I access your URL using either Firefox or Chrome, I get ***No history available - see Help***. Do you need to log in to see results? If so then your software will need to do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, given your code - the problem is almost certainly one of interpolation. Because the `&` in your URL is going to be interpreted by the shell you're spawning as 'background this process'.

That's almost certainly not what you want. Why not just use LWP natively?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore?linkname=pcassay_nucleotide&from_aid=504934,1806,1805,1674';

my $content = get $url;

print $content;

open ( my $output_fh, '>', 'output.html' ) or die $!;
print {$output_fh} $content; 
close ( $output_fh );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as you said , the problem was related with "&" sign. I use substitution and replace all & with \& , then it is ok.